Relationship between normalizers of different Sylow $p$-subgroups
My question is this: given a finite group G, and Sylow $p$-subgroups $P_1, P_2$, is there anything we can say about $N_G (P_1)$ and $N_G (P_2)$? Specifically, I'm wondering if we can guarantee that these two normalizers are not equal/if we can always find an element in one that is not in the other or vice versa.
The context is that I was trying to come up with a proof for why $N_G (N_G(P)) = N_G(P)$, and the method I was following involved proving that if g is an element of the LHS, then it is an element of the RHS. I supposed that if g is not an element of the RHS, then $g^{-1}Pg \neq P$. Interpreting the conjugation action on p-Sylow subgroups, we know $g^{-1}Pg$ must be some other Sylow $p$-subgroup $P'$. What I want to do here is find some element $g_1 \in N_G(P)$ such that $g_1 P' g_1^{-1} \neq P'$, i.e. $g_1 \notin N_G(P')$, so that the overall conjugation $g g_1 g^{-1}$ will not send $P$ to $P$, and thus $g\notin N_G(N_G(G))$. But it's not clear to me if such a $g_1$ actually exists, so I was curious if there was some way to describe the relationship between such normalizers to answer this. I imagine there should be a way to find one since this contrapositive statement should hold true? But I'm not fully sure if this relies more heavily on other factors of the problem or not.
I would appreciate any insight, and I'm aware of simpler proofs of the original statement (i.e. interpreting $P$ as a subgroup of $N_G(P)$), but my question is mainly interested in the properties of the normalizers within my proof attempt. I would also be interested in any counterexamples to $g_1$ existing (as in, finite groups where there are distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups that have the same normalizer). If it's not always possible to find such a $g_1$ in this broad setting, is there some other way of salvaging my proof by incorporating other aspects of the problem?

The normalizers are the stabilizers of Sylow II action, so they are conjugate.

If $P’ \subseteq N(P)$, then $P’=P$, and if $N(P’)=N(P)$, then $P’=P$ might help. This is what Lang puts as exercises before your statement and can be used in the proof.

Thanks! I forgot that by construction P is a normal subgroup of N(P)

Answer:
$N_G (P)$ is a group in which $P$ is a normal (Sylow $p$-) subgroup, by construction. By Sylow II, this implies that $P$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup in $N_G (P)$. Ergo if another Sylow $p$-subgroup $Q \subseteq N_G (P)$, then this would imply $Q = P$. So, distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups cannot be contained in each other's normalizers, meaning their respective normalizers also cannot be identical.

Maybe good to know in addition to the answer of Yash:

Proposition If $P,Q \in Syl_p(G)$, then $N_G(P) \cap Q = P \cap Q = P \cap N_G(Q)$.

Proof Apply Sylow Theory in the subgroup $N_G(P)$: $Q \cap N_G(P)$ is a $p$-group in $N_G(P)$, and hence must be contained in some Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$. Since $P \unlhd N_G(P)$, $P$ is the unique one and so $Q \cap N_G(P) \subseteq P$. (Note that $Q$ does not even have to be a Sylow $p$-group here, just being a $p$-subgroup suffices.) The other containment is trivial and by symmetry the proposition follows. $\square$
